# Unable to compile Gazebo with Dart. Bizarre error no static lib found error

Tags: gazebo, ubuntu-14.04

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I was trying to compile Gazebo with Dart on Ubuntu 14.04, but alas I keep getting this bizarre error:

gazebo: error while loading shared libraries: libgazebo_common.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Know, I know this error is very similar to one of the ones described in the tutorial for installing Gazebo, but that error is libgazebo_common.so.1 not .4. Moreover, I tried the solution suggested on that page:

```
echo '/usr/local/lib' | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/gazebo.conf 
sudo ldconfig
```

but it did not work. Any idea how to resolve this error? I tried both following the directions on the websites and when that did not work, using the .sh script provided in the following git repo to do it, but that did not work. Any idea what could be causing my error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9004/unable-to-compile-gazebo-with-dart.-bizarre-error-no-static-lib-found-error./) by [Skylion](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1252/skylion/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-06-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2015-06-26**:
Did you check that `libgazebo_common.so.4` is inside `/usr/local/lib`? Have you tried `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` instead?

**Comment by [Skylion](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1252/skylion/) on 2015-06-26**:
That worked, but now I am getting new errors:Error opening log file: "/home/skylion/.gazebo/gzserver.log"
Error opening log file: "/home/skylion/.gazebo/default.log"
Error opening log file: "/home/skylion/.gazebo/gzclient.log"
Error opening log file: "/home/skylion/.gazebo/default.log"
Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must
reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.

terminate cal

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2015-06-26**:
humm maybe try deleting your log files? `rm ~/.gazebo/*.log`

**Comment by [Skylion](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1252/skylion/) on 2015-06-26**:
Thank you, @chapulina your solution worked. If you write it up, I'll accept it in answer form. Update: I spoke too soon, it' s not running dart now: ***** Internal Program Error - assertion (dartChildLink.get() != __null) failed in virtual void gazebo::physics::DARTJoint::Init():
/home/skylion/gazebo/gazebo/physics/dart/DARTJoint.cc(84): dartChildLink pointer is NULL. Regardless, since this is a different issue I have opened up a new question on the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When building gazebo from source and installing it outside of */usr* (i.e. */usr/local*) the loader needs to know about where to find the libraries. To make it easy, gazebo provides the setup.sh script. So:

- Source the setup.sh file in /usr/local installation (*. /usr/local/share/gazebo/setup.sh*)
- Install gazebo (*cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr*) into */usr* will workaround about this kind of problems, if this is an option for you.
- As Louise pointed in the comment, the library path used by gazebo is a arch-dependent path (i.e. */usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu* on 64 bits systems). I won't recommend to use */etc/ld.so.conf.d* for pointing it to */usr/local*, it could end up in a security risk.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2015-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Skylion](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1252/skylion/) on 2015-06-26**:
I tried source setup.sh and my DCMAKE_INSTALL_PATH did equal /usr